# Present a View Controller Programmatically OS X

Tags: macos, swift, nsviewcontroller, nsstoryboard

so maybe this is so easy and I'm being dense but..

I'm trying to open a view controller that is displayed on my main.storyboard programatically from my MenuBarController. The View Controller doesn't have any segues attached to it but I have given the view controller a storyboard ID of Test.

**This is for OS X so apologies I'm new to the storyboard and Segue features.**

I've been trying this:

```
let storyBoard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)! as NSStoryboard
let myViewController = storyBoard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("test") as NSViewController
self.presentViewControllerAsModalWindow(myViewController)
```

But receive an error:

> [NSNib initWithNibNamed:bundle:] could not load the nibName:
>   TestApp.MenuBarController in bundle (null).

Comment: `var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("test") as YourVCName`
`self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

does this work? Also are you using swift 1.1 or 1.2?

Comment: I'm using Swift 1.1 and I'm afraid that code doesn't work...

Comment: I've finally been put straight. The problem was I was trying to trigger self.presentviewcontroller from a view controller that was in the Application Scene section of the storyboard. It works perfectly firing from any other view actually within the app!!